# Firebase function predeploy error :Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I tried to run
`firebase deploy --only functions` in my ionic project and this error message show up

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local>firebase deploy --only functions
=== Deploying to 'testing-ed384'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint
npm ERR! missing script: lint

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CJ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-13T14_26_34_575Z-debug.log
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\functions" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\local\\functions" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\local\\functions" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because:

- You don't have eslint installed. This could happen if at the time you ran `firebase init functions` you answered no when prompted `Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style?` and/or you answered no when prompted to install dependencies. If that's the case reinitialize the environment to get it installed.
- You're missing the eslint package in your package.js file. To check/fix this open it up and look if you have something in the lines of:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by re-initiating firebase init. Then not selecting to use eslint. After that firebase deploy run normally.