# how to resolve Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

trying to deploy firebase functions , and I am now lost , no matter what i try nothing is working for me
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337001/firebase-function-predeploy-error-command-terminated-with-non-zero-exit-code1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219322/error-functions-predeploy-error-command-terminated-with-non-zero-exit-code254)  also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429390/firebase-deploy-errors-starting-with-non-zero-exit-code-space-in-project-path) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998720/firebase-deploy-error-enoent)   along with multiple other solutions i found on stackoverflow and other sites (tried everything that i can find related to this error) , and nothing seems to be working for me

I am using **Node v14.16.0** and **firebase tools version 9.8.0**

does this mean i am missing some packages in firebase-tools? i have also installed the firebase-tools multiple times just to make sure each and everything is installed correctly, tried pretty much every thing in above mentioned links but nothing seems to be working

**this is what i am stuck at:**

```
  13:37  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "C:\Users\r\Desktop\cfnc\functions" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\r\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\r\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\r\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\r\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "C:\\Users\\r\\Desktop\\cfnc\\functions" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "C:\\Users\\r\\Desktop\\cfnc\\functions" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

**can someone please help point me to the correct solution for this issue ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did some research in your error and the part in your error that says:

```
  path: 'npm --prefix "C:\\Users\\r\\Desktop\\cfnc\\functions" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
```

Means that you don't have the `lint` script in the package.json. If you modified properly your package json as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48349057/9330208):

Linux

```
"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
]
```

PowerShell

```
"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix $Env:RESOURCE_DIR run lint"
]
```

Cmd.exe

```
"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint"
]
```

And it didn't work I suggest that you try the steps on this [thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/822#issuecomment-406754186) of github. Also it would be helpful that you share your package.json